# js How to get all dates from yearOfWeek or only accept next week dates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dayjs

In my app people can enter his work times for next week. So I want to prevent current dates or dates that are later then the next week. I only want to accept next week dates (or dates from a week year).

I found a function in dayjs where I can get the yearOfWeek

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');

const weekOfYear = require('dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear');
dayjs.extend(weekOfYear);

const year = dayjs(new Date()).week();
```

In my app they are also a specific day limit where you can not anymore send your worker times until another week started.

All works but how can I only accept next week dates and not current dates or week that are later then next week ?

I found a way to prevent sending dates at specific time.

I have two variables:

```
let untilDayNumber = 5; // the number of the day in a week so 5 is friday at friday the user cannot send worker times anymore.
let untilDayHours = 21; // at how much o clock I prevent send the dates so when its friday but under 21 o clock then he can still send his times
```

I only need a way where I accept only dates from next week or from a specific calendar week.

CurrentCode:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');

const weekOfYear = require('dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear');
dayjs.extend(weekOfYear);

const weekOfYear = dayjs(new Date()).week();

let preventSendDay = 5;
let preventSendHours = 21;

// user worker times
let dates = [new Date(2024, 2, 8), new Date(2024, 2, 9), new Date(2024, 2, 10)];
const today = new Date();

const day = today.getDay() === 0 ? 7 : today.getDay(); // get day number

const hours = today.getHours(); // get day hours

// Now find a solution to accept only next week worker times


// prevent send worker times at specific day
if (
  day > preventSendDay ||
  (day === preventSendDay && hours >= preventSendHours)
) {
  console.log('PREVENT SENDING WORKER TIMES');
}
```